# ElasticSearch JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, promise, mocha.js

Testing the below in a Mocha/Chain start-up block, the code never waits as expected. Instead, the log reports on the start of creation, then logs from a test (not included), then reports the index creation is complete.

Should not Mocha not exit the before-each block until the Promise is reolved or rejected?

What have I missed?

```
module.exports.prototype.setup = function (term) {
    this.logger.info("Re-creating the index '%s'", $index);
    return this.client.indices.delete({
        index: $index,
        ignore: [404]
    }).then((err, resp, respcode) => {
        this.logger.info("Creating index '%s'", $index);
        return this.client.indices.create({
            index: $index,
            body: this.schemaBody
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Promises are not blocking. They are asynchronous not synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calling this code from the Mocha/Chai test? Is it in a `beforeEach`? From the [Mocha Documentation](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) you can do one of the following:

```
// [Option A] return a promise
beforeEach(() => {
  return setup("foo");
});

// [Option B]: add a `done` parameter, and call it when you are done
beforeEach((done) => {
  return setup("foo").then(() => {
     done();
  });
});
```

Comment: So often I forget that `return` statement that I'm surprised I don't check it more thoroughly....! Looked at the code for so long, I could not longer see it, thanks!

Comment: Yes it's very easy to forget ... done it many times myself! The return in the first case (Option A) is necessary. The return in the second case should be optional (Option B).

Comment: @LeeGee this is the part when you choose a right answer and maybe hand out some upvotes ;)

Comment: Ah! I've been trying to work out how SO works. If the question is good enough to answer, should you not also up-vote it?

Comment: @JamesLawson — I spent a lot of years with Perl, and its implicit return values. Only now do I miss them....!

Answer (score 2):

You need to write an [async test](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) to test promises.

```
it("should do something", (done) => {
    setup("stuff").then((index) => {
        /* test index */
        done();
    });
});
```

You can also return a promise from the test and mocha will wait for it to resolve.

```
it("should do something", () => {
    return setup("stuff").then((index) => {
        /* test index */
    });
});
```